# storing reference to image on SD efficiently in DB

Tags: android, database, image, sqlite, blob

I'm pretty new to programming Android and I have a problem - I'm creating an app which stores "funny" images and enables user to view all of them, rate them (at least I want to make it so ;) ). I was trying to make a very simple database which stores images as BLOBs but someone on forum told me that this is a bad idea - so I decided to store images on SD like (this code is mainly from Stack although):

```
private void savePicToSD(){
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Saving...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //getting BitMap from ImageView
    Bitmap imageToSave=((BitmapDrawable)preview.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

    // getting env var representing path
    String root= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),root,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    File dir=new File(root+DIR_NAME_);



     dir.mkdirs();

    String fileNam="Image-"+FILE_COUNTER_+".jpg";
    FILE_COUNTER_=FILE_COUNTER_.add(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
    File fileSav=new File(dir,fileNam);


    //I don't use try-with-resources because of API lvl
    FileOutputStream out=null;
    try{
        out=new FileOutputStream(fileSav);

        //saving compressed file ot the dir
        imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,90,out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error during saving.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Image saved.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

after making it I now don't know how to store this "reference" and how to implement "fetching data from DB" - I was thinking about storing (with some sort of other data releated to specific photo) in DB string contatining path to the image and later while reading data from DB, read also the image - but how to do this efficiently? (I know that fetching data from DB has to be done as a Thread (AsyncTask ? ))?

Comment: Thanks are very unnecessary

Comment: `(I know that fetching data from DB has to be done as a Thread (AsyncTask ? ))?` No. Not at all.

Comment: `Thanks are very unnecessary ` Dont agree @Kling Klang. They are very welcome after giving help. In fact if there is no thank you it's disappointing.

Comment: @greenapps Not here. We're all here to help. But the only way to thank is to accept an answer and/or like it. Or like a comment. There's no need to explicitly say "thank you".

Comment: To like it? This is no facebook.

Comment: @greenapps Like = upvote. Try being a bit elastic, man...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best you can do is storing the path of the image in BDD or a relative path and then access it

Comment: I have modified the answer, sorry, i only wanted to help

Comment: Okay, no problem  - and does anyone know why this Code stores images so that they sometimes appear in the normal Gallery? I have found that android scans sd for images but I thought  it woluldn't do so in this case? Maybe someone knows how to provide android from doing so?

Answer (score 1):

Store imagePath/fileName in your local database along with saving the image in the file system(SD card), and then when you want to get back that image just fetch that image from the file system by using imagePath/fileName stored in database.

I hope that you know how to create file and store in SD card.